sqlc generate error "# package db sqldb\queries\user_data.sql:1:1: relation "user_data" does not exist"
users.sql
-- name: CreateUser :one
INSERT INTO "users" ("id", "created_at", "updated_at", "name")
VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)
RETURNING *;


sqlc.yaml
version: "2"
sql:
  - engine: "postgresql"
    queries: "sql/queries"
    schema: "sql/schema"
    gen:
      go:
        # package: "internal"
        out: "internal/database"
        sql_package: "pgx/v5"

001_users.sql
-- +goose UP

CREATE TABLE "users"(
    "id" UUID PRIMARY KEY,
    "created_at" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    "updated_at" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    "name" TEXT NOT NULL
);

-- +goose DOWN

DROP TABLE "users";

when i try to generate i get an error like this
$ sqlc generate
# package 
sql\queries\users.sql:1:1: relation "users" does not exist

is anyone know how to solve this error.
i try every that is it's not coming
but for som one or two tables creating sqlc generate works
-- name: GetPost :one
SELECT * FROM post
WHERE id = $1 LIMIT 1;

-- +goose Up
CREATE TABLE post (
    id int NOT NULL,
    title text,
    body text,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

-- +goose Down
DROP TABLE post;


created sqlc generate for post 
this is my sqlc.yaml
version: "2"
sql:
  - engine: "postgresql"
    queries: "sqldb/queries"
    schema: "sqldb/schema"
    gen:
      go:
        package: "db"
        out: "migrations"
        # sql_package: "pgx/v5"

i deleted the sql folder and create a new db called rss and  sqldb folder then according to document in the goose i get that and name it 001_post.sql and in query i pasted the post.sql in the document.
and again i tried the goose up comment then the new post table crated in my new db rss.
then i came to the root folder i ran sqlc generate then it's generate the code same exactly i did for the user again and i get error.

I duplicated your setup (above the "when i try to generate" line) and this worked fine for me (sqlc v1.26.0). Please ensure you have no additional files under the sql sub-directories (and your question contains the full content of the files you do have). "create a new db" note that this is irrelevant (sqlc does not connect to your database).

Sorry - also just noticed that the error in the question subject refers to user_data whereas it's users in the question body; please edit the question and make this consistent.

Same for me I tried yesterday with no changes and it works for me too. I don't know how that happened

The reason this might happen is because of the table name mismatch in the "001_user.sql" and in the "users.sql". Make sure both the names match and then run: sqlc generate

sqlc does not actually access the database (it parses the DDL in the migration files). This means it's not really relevant whether the migration has been run or not (if it's not been run, then OP would see a runtime error when they run the final executable and it attempts to execute the query). As per my comment above I was able to run sqlc successfully using copied/pasted versions of the files OP provided. I suspect the info in the question is incomplete.

I agree, you're right. I was able to reproduce the error without running the migrations. This is happening when there is a table name mismatch in both the files. Thanks for pointing it out.

The schema key in the sqlc.yaml file should point to your database migrations path, in this case the path to the 001_users.sql file. I had the same error but this fixed it. Here is how my configuration looks like after.
sqlc.yaml
version: "2"
sql:
  - engine: "postgresql"
    queries: "./db/query"
    schema: "./db/migrations"
    gen:
      go:
        package: "db"
        out: "./db/sqlc/"
        sql_package: "pgx/v5"
        emit_json_tags: true

db/query/account.sql
-- name: CreateAccount :one
INSERT INTO accounts (
  owner,
  balance,
  currency
) VALUES (
  $1, $2, $3
)
RETURNING *;

db/migrations/000001_init_schema.up.sql
CREATE TABLE "accounts" (
  "id" bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
  "owner" varchar NOT NULL,
  "balance" bigint NOT NULL,
  "currency" varchar NOT NULL,
  "created_at" timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT (now())
);


i just faced the same issue all i did was to change the +goose UP to +goose Up and +goose DOWN to +goose Down
-- +goose Up

CREATE TABLE "users"(
    "id" UUID PRIMARY KEY,
    "created_at" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    "updated_at" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    "name" TEXT NOT NULL
);

-- +goose Down

DROP TABLE "users";

